# Is it better to use one or many contexts

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

We have an application that has 3 contexts for connecting to 3 SQL Server databases, under the same server.

Our DBAs are arguing that these three connections are being costly for the server.

My question is: is it true? Are three connections more costly than one? How can I measure it?

What is the best practice for dealing with this sittuation on Entity Framework?

Also, we are accessing three databases and our DBAs are arguing we are doing three connections. Is it a coincidence or each context really corresponds to a different connection?

Comment: If the contexts have different schema, and are therefore different context classes, I don't see any other way of doing it.  Even if they are the same schema but physically different databases, you will require 3 open connections if you use them at the same time.

Comment: Sounds like they aren't DBA's... @BradleyUffner is right, 3 DBs need 3 different connections. Three connections are more costly than one but if you're pooling correctly then it really shouldn't matter, the connections actually stay open and then your program just grabs a handle to an open connection from the pool. I think?

Comment: Have the DBAs proposed any ideas to fix the "problem"?

Comment: Yes, each context corresponds to a different schema.
Well, they said we must use as few as possible, I found some resources online teaching how to do it, but it seems to me that use one single wouldn't reduce what is being used, I mean, we would keep fetching same amount of data, I guess

Comment: Maybe he wants to move each db to separate server in future/production

Comment: Seems to me like you'll probably get several orders of magnitude more performance improvement with some intelligent caching or restructuring of your schema than you'll see reducing the number of connections by two thirds.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I humbly agree with you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework under the hood uses [ADO.Net Connection Pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling).

Excerpt:

> Connection pooling reduces the number of times that new connections must be opened. The pooler maintains ownership of the physical connection. It manages connections by keeping alive a set of active connections for each given connection configuration. Whenever a user calls Open on a connection, the pooler looks for an available connection in the pool. If a pooled connection is available, it returns it to the caller instead of opening a new connection. When the application calls Close on the connection, the pooler returns it to the pooled set of active connections instead of closing it. Once the connection is returned to the pool, it is ready to be reused on the next Open call.
>
> Pooling connections can significantly enhance the performance and scalability of your application. By default, connection pooling is enabled in ADO.NET. Unless you explicitly disable it, the pooler optimizes the connections as they are opened and closed in your application. You can also supply several connection string modifiers to control connection pooling behavior. For more information, see "Controlling Connection Pooling with Connection String Keywords" later in this topic.

.

> Our DBAs are arguing that these three connections are being costly for the server.

He needs to Define costly. If you need 3 connections, you need three connections, you can't just magically reduce the number of connections.

> Are three connections more costly than one?

Yes.  Everything has a Pro/Con to it.  If it simpler to write, maintain and have better performance with 3, it not as simple as just saying 3 vs 1.

> What is the best practice for dealing with this sittuation on Entity Framework?

I don't think based on your question (no example contexts, why there are 3 databases, if they are all in use at the same time by the same client or not) it can really be answered in your case.

Comment: Erik, I agree with you. Thanks for your answer.

We use three contexts because there are three databases, all three with different schema, each one bellonging to a different system (CRM, Market Data, other vendor's data).

All three databases are inside the same sql server. ADO.Net allows to use a single connection and refer to the database in the query itself, on Entity it is not that simple. Tha is what our DBAs were arguing against Entity. But it seems more to be a matter of optmize our code than reducing connections, right?

Anyway, thank you so much for your answer